# jquery registration form, email if statement not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am making a registration form using jquery to dynamically update each field as the user enters information, for some reason when I go to compare emails the if statement does not run. any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Why are you making so many post calls??

Comment: Only post the code relevant to the question. The reg.js part has so much code it gets a little confusing.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this link which shows proper [email validation in php](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php#example-5571). Also then if the mail is valid apply the check if it is already taken or not. I wrote to check if emails exist after because Database query are costly and better not to have query for all bogus data also.

Hope this helps you out

also change

```
<input type = text id = email>
```

to

```
<input type = email id = email>
```

which is supported in html5